# Extract Variable from jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a single object that returns the following:
`{left: "642px", top: "305px", opacity: "1"}`

I am trying to break these out into three separate variables: `var left`, `var top`, and `var opacity`

What is the simplest way to go about this?

Comment: How is this a "jQuery object"?

Comment: How are you using the variables later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
var data = {left: "642px", top: "305px", opacity: "1"};
var left = data.left,
    top = data.top,
    opacity = data.opacity;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dXxUc/1/

Comment: +1 as readability and maintenance counts!

Answer (score 3):

```
var left = object.left, top = object.top, opacity = object.opacity;
```

JavaScript doesn't have (currently) any fancy decomposing assignments like some other languages do.

Comment: This is probably the best approach, but it's better (from a readability perspective) if you use multiple lines.

Answer (score 3):

No shortcuts here:

```
var left = obj.left,
top = obj.top,
opacity = obj.opacity;
```

Answer (score 2):

If this object is named `myObject`, you can retrieve the vars with :

```
var left = myObject.left;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you intend to use them. If you are just going to save them into those variables once and there is one object then

```
var left = data.left;//or data["left"]
var top = data.top;//or data["top"]
var opacity = data.opacity;//or data["opacity"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the global scope, there *is* a shortcut to doing this:

```
for (p in o){
    if(o.hasOwnProperty(p)){
        window[p] = o[p];
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't use `var`, but adds the properties to the `window` object. Properties of the `window` object are globally accessible directly in JS.